# What happens with an object when passed by const reference is added to a container like std::map?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, std, sfml

I'm having a problem with understanding the concept of ownership of objects in C++.

To give you a little bit of a background, I am programming a small app in C++ 11 using SFML 2.1 on Windows using Visual Studio 2013.

Basically I wrote a class `AssetsManager` to wrap around my `sf::Texture` objects. I'd like to store my textures in a `std::map` to be able to refer to and find them easily with a key. That map is a private member of the `AssetsManager` class.

I have two public member functions for "registering" (adding) a texture object to the map and getting a texture object from the map.

This is how I declare the map in my class header:

```
private:
    // Resources are mapped to a key for easy access.
    std::map < std::string, sf::Texture > m_textures;
```

And these are the two function definitions in the cpp file:

```
sf::Texture AssetsManager::GetTexture(const std::string& key)
{
    return m_textures[key];
}

bool AssetsManager::RegisterTexture(const std::string& key, const sf::Texture& texture)
{
    // If a texture in the std::map already exists with the given key, return false.
    if (m_textures.count(key))
        return false;

    // Add the texture with key to the std::map.
    m_textures.insert(std::make_pair(key, texture));

    return true;
}
```

In my main function, I do this:

```
AssetsManager assets;

sf::Texture myTexture;
myTexture.loadFromFile("Assets/MyCharacter.png");
assets.RegisterTexture("Hero Character", myTexture);
```

What I do not understand is what happens with the `myTexture` variable declared in my main function.
I added the object to the map, so I can get it by calling

```
assets.GetTexture("Hero Character");
```

Can I do something with the `myTexture` variable in the main function though?

Are both objects the same one? Or did the ownership transfer from `myTexture` to the object in the map, so that `myTexture` became somewhat empty?

It would be nice if someone could clarify this, so I can continue my work.

I even bumped my head around if using pointers would be the right choice here, but I'd like the `AssetsManager` to have full control over the *Textures*, i.e. "own" them, not just pointers to the objects, if you understand what I mean.

Comment: The map is saving a copy of your texture. Hope that was what you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step by step analysis:

```
m_textures.insert(std::make_pair(key, texture));
```

First, `std::make_pair(T&&, U&&)` [takes](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/make_pair/) *forwarding-references*, and instantiates a pair of [*decayed*](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/decay/) types: `std::pair<std::decay_t<T>, std::decay_t<U>>` from arguments supplied. In your case those types are as follows:

```
T = const std::string&, std::decay_t<T> = std::string
U = const sf::Texture&, std::decay_t<U> = sf::Texture
```

Having that said, the pair is defined as `std::pair<std::string, sf::Texture>`, and since the original values had been *const lvalue references*, both arguments `key` and `texture` have been *copy-constructed* and therefore copies have been stored within an instance of the returned `std::pair`.

Now, the `insert` member-function. `std::map` has its [overload](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/) taking another *forwarding-reference*, described as follows:

> Value to be **copied to** (or **moved as**) the inserted element.

That being said, the argument of `insert` (deduced type `P = std::pair<std::string, sf::Texture>`, with `P&&`) is `std::forward<P>`ed to the newly created node's pair that your instance of `std::map` stores. This results in *moving* your pair, which is described as:

> The object is initialized with the contents of the *pr* `pair` object.
>   **The corresponding member of *pr* is passed to the constructor of each of its members.**

However, if either of those members don't implement *move-constructor*, the operation falls back into regular *copy-construction* for that specific member.

To sum up, with `m_textures.insert(std::make_pair(key, texture));` statement in *worst case scenario* you may end up with two (possibly expensive) copies of both arguments made. The only benefit is you don't have to worry about *ownership*, as the `std::map` itself gains a brand new copy of those elements. As a side note, you actually never have to worry about *ownership* when someone takes your object *by reference*. It's very unlikely someone will even think of storing a reference or an address to such object, as its origin is unknown and one can't control its lifetime.

You can try to optimize this operation replacing it with following [`emplace`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/emplace) member function's call:

```
m_textures.emplace(std::piecewise_construct
                 , std::forward_as_tuple(key)
                 , std::forward_as_tuple(texture));
```

which will use the arguments to *emplace* a pair directly within the associated node.

Nonetheless, I feel you should use `std::shared_ptr` for `sf::Texture` instances, since as the name suggests it can store large amount of data.

Additionally, consider reimplementing your `GetTexture` member function (with overloaded *const-qualified* one) to return *reference*:

```
sf::Texture& AssetsManager::GetTexture(const std::string& key)
//~~~~~~~~~^
{
    return m_textures[key];
}

const sf::Texture& AssetsManager::GetTexture(const std::string& key) const
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^                                                   ~~~~^
{
    return m_textures.at(key);
}
```

because otherwise each call to `GetTexture` will make a copy as well.

Comment: I ended up storing std::shared_ptrs in my class. Thank you!